# Groovy string replaceAll not working as expected

Tags: regex, string, groovy

I have a string of valid XML (containing XML tags, attributes, comments, whitespaces, etc.) that contains special tokens of the form:

> %(*)

For example, `%(testLibDir)`, or `%(ivySettingsFile)`, etc.

I am trying to replace all instances of `%(*)` with `${*}`. So for example, if `%(testLibDir)` exists within my XML string (regardless of how many occurrences), then I want it converted into `${testLibDir}`, etc.

My best attempt thus far:

```
static void main(String[] args) {
    // In reality the XML string will be generated dynamically at runtime.
    String xml = """
  <project name="some-name" default="dist" basedir="." xmlns:ivy="antlib:org.apache.ivy.ant">

  <!-- specify properties in build.properties -->
  <property file="build.properties" />

  <taskdef name="ivy-configure" classname="org.apache.ivy.ant.IvyConfigure" />
  <taskdef name="ivy-resolve" classname="org.apache.ivy.ant.IvyResolve" />
  <taskdef name="ivy-retrieve" classname="org.apache.ivy.ant.IvyRetrieve" />
  <taskdef name="ivy-cleancache" classname="org.apache.ivy.ant.IvyCleanCache" />

  <!-- Identify the Ivy settings file to use -->
  <ivy:settings file="%(ivySettingsFile)" />

  <target name="test-resolve">
    <delete>
      <fileset dir="%(testLibDir)" includes="*.jar" />
    </delete>
    <ivy:resolve file="test-ivy.xml" conf="compile" />
    <ivy:retrieve pattern="%(testLibDir)/[artifact]-[type]-[revision].[ext]" conf="compile" />
  </target>
  """
    println "Final XML is:\n${xml.replaceAll('%(', '\${').replaceAll(')', '}')}"
}
```

The `println` above produces the following stacktrace:

```
log4j:ERROR Could not find value for key log4j.appender.stdout.layout
log4j:WARN No such property [file] in org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender.
Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unclosed group near index 2
%(
^
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.error(Pattern.java:1955)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.accept(Pattern.java:1813)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.group0(Pattern.java:2908)
    (rest of stack trace omitted for brevity)
```

Any ideas where I'm going awry and what I can do to fix my string replacement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a regex like:

```
/%\(([^()]*)\)/
```

to match

- `%` - a percentage sing
- `\(` - a literal `(`
- `([^()]*)` - Group 1 capturing 0+ chars other than `(` and `)`
- `\)` - a literal `)`

Note that the pattern itself is better defined with a slashy strings, and the literal `$` in the replacement pattern should be escaped with a literal `\` to be treated as a literal dollar symbol. `$1` is a backreference to the value captured by Group 1.

[Groovy demo](https://ideone.com/iqSl1z):

```
println xml.replaceAll(/%\(([^()]*)\)/, '\\${$1}')
```